# Pivot on Case Ageing and groups them based on time passed showing the months not hours

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to pivot the time difference and group them into hours like

- 0-4 hours
- 5-8 Hours
- 8 Hours +

Got the time difference but can't figure how to pivot and get the groups.

[Excel link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r4nXM7nLDTVsa4kvHHOf8_ORxW4zYnvH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The "Real Time Ageing" is displayed as minutes instead of hours?

Comment: @Lee in hours and mins like [hh]:mm.  formatted to the mentioned one